# Mule ESB: component and message source in one thing

Tags: java, spring, components, mule

I'd like to implement a flow in Mule that gets a message and returns multiple messages, not just one. However, I don't want to return a collection. I want the output messages to be sent out one-by-one. What I have in mind is something like a [message source](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Sources#MessageSources-customms) that is activated by receiving a message.

An example flow would be something like this:

```
message [a bunch of values for some SQL placeholders] -->

--> VM inbound-endpoint -->

--> Custom DB component/connector
(which executes an SQL query with the information from the inbound message)
"a new message is generated for each row returned by the SELECT query" -->

--> VM outbound-enpoint
```

The first thought I had was to write a component that implements both [MessageSource](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/source/MessageSource.html) and [Callable](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/lifecycle/Callable.html) interfaces. But that doesn't seem to work.

Any idea / suggestions ?

Comment: You would like to send multiple messages one by one to the VM outbound endpoint?

Comment: Yes. In the same way a message source would do.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather return a collection and then use Splitter or Foreach to send the items one-by-one. But if you really need a custom processor that takes in a single message and puts out multiple messages, a pretty simple approach would be extending [AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/outbound/AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.html).

Comment: A splitter is not what I need. The inbound message may contain just some input parameters. The SQL flow I posted is just an example to give a real idea of what I need to do. Just to stop people asking themselves "why" I need to do this : )

Comment: Not sure if I understand your need. A custom splitter would work just like a message source that sends out a sequence of messages. Unless you want to implement something like a listener that gets triggered every now and then and then sends individual messages.

Comment: As mentioned above I don't want to send a sequence of messages, but messages in sequence. Yes, more or less like in a listener design pattern. However my component would need to end at some point.